# $scope always coming as not defined in angular js unit testing

Tags: angularjs

I have a sample angular app like below

```
(function () {

    angular.module("WatchApp", [])
        .controller("WatchController", function ($scope) {
            $scope.message = "hello";
        });
}());
```

I have a test case like below

```
describe("WatchController", function () {

    var $scope;

    beforeEach(module("WatchApp"));
    beforeEach(
        inject(function (_$controller_) {
            $scope: {};
            controller: _$controller_("WatchController", {
                $scope: $scope
            });

        }));

    describe("Initialization", function () {
        it("Should be truthy", function () {
            expect(true).toBeTruthy();
        })
    })

});
```

I know the test case is not right, just wrote to see whether the configurations are correct, but it always give the error like below

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0) WatchController Initialization Should be truthy FAILED
        TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$scope.message = "hello"') (line 5)
        C:/robin/Studies/Angularjs/ut/app/controllers/watchController.js:5:19
        [native code]
        instantiate@C:/robin/Studies/Angularjs/ut/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4680:61
        $controller@C:/robin/Studies/Angularjs/ut/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10130:39
        C:/robin/Studies/Angularjs/ut/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2194:21
        C:/robin/Studies/Angularjs/ut/test/controllers/watchControllerSpec.js:9:38
        invoke@C:/robin/Studies/Angularjs/ut/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4665:24
        workFn@C:/robin/Studies/Angularjs/ut/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2965:26
        inject@C:/robin/Studies/Angularjs/ut/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2931:28
        C:/robin/Studies/Angularjs/ut/test/controllers/watchControllerSpec.js:7:15
        global code@C:/robin/Studies/Angularjs/ut/test/controllers/watchControllerSpec.js:1:9
```

Please let me know what is the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    inject(function (_$controller_, _$scope_) {
        $scope: _$scope_;
        controller: _$controller_("WatchController", {
            '$scope': $scope
        });

    }));
```

Comment: Its throwing the below exception.
      Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope

Comment: Woops, changed some stuff above, give that a go?

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure inject and use `$rootScope` properly in your test.

```js
describe("WatchController", function () {

  var $scope,
      $controller;

  beforeEach(module("WatchApp"));
  beforeEach(
    inject(function (_$controller_, _$rootScope_) {
      $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
      $controller = _$controller_("WatchController", {
        $scope: $scope
      });
    }));

  describe("Initialization", function () {
    it("Should be truthy", function () {
      expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it("should set a message", function () {
      expect($scope.message).toBe("hello");
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: don't need root scope it was because I am using : instead of = to

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed by changing

```
inject(function (_$controller_) {
            $scope: {};
            controller: _$controller_("WatchController", {
                $scope: $scope
            });
```

to

```
inject(function (_$controller_) {
            $scope= {};
            controller: _$controller_("WatchController", {
                $scope: $scope
            });
```